# Why "puts {a: 1}" is a violation of Rubocop

Tags: ruby, rubocop

The expression `{ a: 1 }` is not a problem,

but Rubocop's point( `Lint/Syntax: unexpected token tCOLON(Using Ruby 3.1 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)` ) appears in the expression
`puts { a: 1 }`.

Does anyone know why this statement is against the rules? If you have a reference, I would appreciate it if you could also give me the URL of it.

I use rubocop version 1.24.1 and set `TargetRubyVersion` in `.rubocop.yml`. ruby versions 2.7, 3.0 and 3.1 were all tested with the same result.

Comment: It’s also a syntax error in Ruby.

Comment: Considering that `puts { a: 1 } #=> SyntaxError: <main>: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'`, I don't understand why Robocop doesn't just allow Ruby to raise the exception, rather than providing its own description of the error; I thought Robocop was only concerned with matters of style.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: this is a *syntax error*. Rubocop cannot even *parse* the code, therefore, there is no way for it to make any decisions about the code, since it already errors out before the rules engine even gets involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Braces in Ruby are used for two things: blocks and hashes. And the Ruby parser isn't going to perform infinite lookahead to determine which one it's looking at. If the current syntactic context accepts a block, Ruby assumes the thing you've given it with braces is a block.

```
puts { a: 1 }
```

First, we parse `puts`. It's an identifier, and it's not a local variable, so we'll assume it's a method on the current (`main`) object. Now we see `{`. It could be either a hash or a block. And we just parsed an identifier starting a function call, so a block would make sense here. Let's parse it as a block.

Next we see `a`. Okay, that's fine. A block with no arguments, and we've got an identifier called `a`. Again, it's not a local variable, so it must be a method on `main`. Then we see `:` and that doesn't work. There's no way a `:` can appear at this point in the syntax, so it's an error. Ruby does *not* go back and try the "hash" option; it's already committed completely to parsing a block, and that failed.

To call `puts` with a single hash argument, use parentheses to disambiguate.

```
puts({ a: 1 })
```

Comment: Very well explained!